# Не получается получить значение из input

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть input. Я сделал чтобы при нажатие на кнопку запускался метод alert со значением input, но получаю undefiend.

```
        <div class="input-selector">
            <div class="login-input-selector">
                <input type="text" class="login-input">
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
    window.onload = function(){
    const singup_btn = document.getElementById("singup-btn");
    const nick_input = document.getElementsByClassName("login-input");

    singup_btn.onclick = function() {
        alert(nick_input.value);
    }

    }
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("login-input")` Возвращает коллекцию элементов, а не один элемент. Воспользуйтесь, например, `document.querySelector()`, если инпут с таким классом у вас один

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName возвращает тебе коллекцию (иными словами массив) из всех элементов, которые содержат класс login-input. [Документация](https://doka.guide/js/getelementsbyclassname/)

Лучше используй querySelector, так как он более универсален и находит именно первый элемент. [Документация](https://doka.guide/js/query-selector/)

Также, от себя, я бы посоветовал использовать не onclick, а метод addEventListener. Он более универсален, понятен и приятнее глазу. [Документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

А если хочешь, чтобы и твоя прога работала, то можешь поправить следующий момент:

```
singup_btn.onclick = function() {
    alert(nick_input[0].value);
}
```

Таким образом ты возьмёшь первый элемент из коллекции и из него сможешь вытянуть значение

Comment: Спасибо все работает. Попробую сделать с querySelector

Answer (score 0):

```js
  window.onload = function() {
    const singup_btn = document.getElementById("singup_btn");
    const nick_input = document.getElementsByClassName("login-input")[0];

    singup_btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert(nick_input.value);
    }) 

  }
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
button{
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
   <div class="input-selector">
     <div class="login-input-selector">
       <input type="text" class="login-input">
     </div>
   </div>
   <button id='singup_btn'>Get Value</button>
```

Как-то так.